# How to install symfony with composer?

Tags: php, windows, symfony, composer-php

I am using Windows 10
When I install symfony2 with:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

Error:

```
bash: composer: command not found
```

Comment: Composer is not install or not in your path

Comment: @Letsrocks you are right. Thanks )).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To downloads symfony, you need to download `symfony.phar` (a small file PHP) from this [link](http://symfony.com/installer).

- Then, you have to move in your usual Web directory `C:\wamp\www on windows` and `/var/www on Linux` ;
- Execute `php symfony.phar new project_name_and_version` for example : `symfony.phar new symfony2.8` to download `Symfony 2.8`.

  Then, you can :
- Change your current directory to `/var/www/html/project_name on Linux` or  `C:\wamp\www on windows`;
- Configure your application in `app/config/parameters.yml` file ;
- And (always) read the documentation at http://symfony.com/doc.

Good luck ^^ !

**Update:**

In `Symfony 4` the `symfony installer` is abandoned. So, to  create a new Symfony application you need:

- to have `PHP 7.1` (or higher)
- to run `php composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton my-project "3.4.*"` in your terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install composer before. From your command line:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php
php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('composer-setup.php')) === '7228c001f88bee97506740ef0888240bd8a760b046ee16db8f4095c0d8d525f2367663f22a46b48d072c816e7fe19959') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Instructions got from here:

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: When i tried php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php

Error: 
bash: composer-setup.php: Permission denied

Comment: Because you run this command in place when you don't have proper privileges. Please do it in /home/user_name or use 'sudo' before used command.

Comment: Try the command from your project's root directory (the one containing the app, vendor, src and web directories).

Answer (score 2):

I tried this one:

```
php symfony.phar new symfony2.8
```

The results is this

```
[RuntimeException]
The Symfony Installer is not compatible with Symfony 4.x or newer versions.
Run this other command to install Symfony using Composer instead:
composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony2.8
```

I tried the suggested command and it start download and install automatically

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony2.8
```

[image]

Comment: To install a version 3 symfony, you can persevere with your original command by putting the version on the end - "symfony new my_first_app 3.4"

Answer (score 1):

The recommanded way to install Symfony is through a command, named `symfony`.

Read the docs from the official symfony website: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html, for more info.

So,

- If you are using MAC/Linux: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#linux-and-mac-os-x-systems
- `$ cd /var/www/`
- `$ symfony new my_project_name` (more readable example: `$ symfony new Blog`). This will create a directory (named `Blog`) inside your `/var/www/` directory, where all the code will be housed.

Then you can install `composer`, as the official docs says, and use it for installing packages inside your Symfony project.

Happy coding!